# Unwanted spaces in recyclerview items in android

Tags: android

I have spaces on recyclerview of my app and i don't know why are there because i have done the samething using the recyclerview and this adapter and did not added unwanted space...but now it is.
Help please

[image: First screenshot]

Here is my home layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="ideias.prime.mungano.Home"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_home">

   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/clients_rv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the recyclerview Item model

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cl_CardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:contentPadding="6dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cl_name"
            android:layout_width="69dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/cl_name"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nome_do_cliente"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cl_name"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/programmer"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cl_work"
            android:layout_width="82dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cl_name"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/cl_work"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/trabalho_do_cliente"
            android:layout_width="99dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/cl_work"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cl_work"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/primeIdeas"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cl_phone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cl_work"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="@string/cl_phone"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/telefone_do_cliente"
            android:layout_width="99dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/cl_phone"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cl_work"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/primeIdeas"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cl_LP"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/trabalho_do_cliente"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:ems="10"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/cl_LP"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cl_LP_info"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/telefone_do_cliente"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:ems="10"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/cl_Lp_info"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cl_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cl_phone"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:ems="10"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/Id"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the Adapter

```
public class Rv_adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Rv_adapter.Holder> {
private Context context;
private List<Model> list = new ArrayList<>();
private Face f;

public Rv_adapter(Context c) {
    context = c;
}

public Rv_adapter(Context c, List<Model> l) {
    this.context = c;
    this.list = l;
}

public void Listenner(Face interfaCe) {
    this.f = interfaCe;
}

@Override
public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(context.getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.rv_model, parent, false);
    return new Holder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Holder holder, int position) {
    holder.Id.setText(list.get(position).getId());
    holder.Name.setText(list.get(position).getName());
    holder.Lp.setText(list.get(position).getLp());
    holder.Phone.setText(list.get(position).getPhone());
    holder.Work.setText(list.get(position).getWork());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private CardView c;
    private TextView Id, Name, Work, Phone, Lp;

    public Holder(View i) {
        super(i);
        c = (CardView) i.findViewById(R.id.cl_CardView);
        Id = (TextView) i.findViewById(R.id.cl_id);
        Name = (TextView) i.findViewById(R.id.nome_do_cliente);
        Work = (TextView) i.findViewById(R.id.trabalho_do_cliente);
        Phone = (TextView) i.findViewById(R.id.telefone_do_cliente);
        Lp = (TextView) i.findViewById(R.id.cl_LP_info);
    }
} // end

public interface Face {
    void Clicked(View v, int position, String cl_id);
}
}
```

Here goes the screenshots of the unwanted spaces on the recyclerview

[image: First]

[image: Secound]

[image: Third]

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the problem to demonstrate what the unwanted space is.

Comment: @bpachev: I jjust edited my post adding the screenshot of the recyclerview with the unwanted spaces

Comment: there's no screenshot. can you check you added it correctly?

Comment: Your TextViews have `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`.. Why?

Comment: @ono... i uploaded images using the picture icon here ... so can you tell me how to upload them? Please

Comment: @cricket_007...i used android:fitsSystemWindows="true" to make them fit to windows of the devices...is it wrong?

Comment: Your images are already uploaded fine. You can view the markdown that I added for the correct way to show the image. And the `android:fitsSystemWindows` attribute is more for Toolbars and NavigationViews... Things that touch the edges of the device and the "system window". TextViews don't do that

Comment: @Janak...it solved man...thanks man

Comment: @cricket_007...thanks man for the Information...thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your recyclerview Height from `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to 
`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`.

and why you are giving scrolling behavior to Your relative layout ??? RecyclerView already hve that!

Comment: but he is using RecyclerView not ListView

Comment: A RecyclerView is essentially the replacement for a list. I would hope that one would want a list to occupy the whole screen, not just the size of its children's elements.

Comment: You can even see here that the RecyclerView has a `match_parent` height. https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Comment: I already face this problem with this white spaces between items.. and i resolve it by giving `layout_height = "wrap_content"`

Comment: I could understand that on the row view of the adapter, but not the RecyclerView...

Comment: That's good to know. Still don't think it is the correct solution ;)

Comment: sir, even he has not posted the full code of the RecyclerView Model see there is LinearLayout at the end of xml!

Comment: It's there... Question just wasn't formatted correctly

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your **recyclerview**, you should make changes in **R.layout.rv_model** file. You have set `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` property to`<TextView>`.

Most of the time, your app won’t need to draw under the status bar or the navigation bar, but if you do: you need to make sure interactive elements (like buttons) aren’t hidden underneath them. That’s what the default behavior of the android:fitsSystemWindows=“true” attribute gives you: it sets the padding of the View to ensure the contents don’t overlay the system windows.

A few things to keep in mind:

fitsSystemWindows is applied depth first — ordering matters: it’s the first View that consumes the insets that makes a difference

Insets are always relative to the full window — insets may be applied even before layout happens, so don’t assume the default behavior knows anything about the position of a View when applying its padding

Any other padding you’ve set is overwritten — you’ll note that paddingLeft/paddingTop/etc is ineffective if you are using android:fitsSystemWindows=”true” on the same View

And, in many cases, such as a full screen video playback, that’s enough. You’d have your full bleed view with no attribute and another full screen ViewGroup with android:fitsSystemWindows=”true” for your controls that you want inset.

Or maybe you want your RecyclerView to scroll underneath a transparent navigation bar — by using android:fitsSystemWindows=”true” in conjunction with android:clipToPadding=”false”, your scrolling content will be behind the controls but, when scrolled to the bottom, the last item will still be padded to be above the navigation bar (rather than hidden underneath!).

Check if you want more information about [android:fitsSystemWindows](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec#.yze7uzha4)

Answer (score 0):

Your item layout is filling one length of your screen each.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" <!-- Here needs to be wrap_content -->
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cl_CardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

And remove `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from the TextViews because they don't need to fit the system window.